# Updating column gives error: "Multipart Identifier could not be bound"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a [Box MDB] column in [manual db] table that needs to be updated based on two set criteria. I used following code:

```
update [02Manual_DB].[dbo].[manual DB]
set [02Manual_DB].[dbo].[manual DB].[Box_MDB] = 'Box-1558'
where [02Manual_DB].[dbo].[1558].[wallet] = [02Manual_DB].[dbo].[manual DB].[Wallet_MDB]
and [02Manual_DB].[dbo].[manual DB].[Box_MDB] like 'Box-1158'
```

However it shows error: The multipart identifier could not be bound. I have tried different things here but none seems to work. Is there any thing I am doing wrong?

Regards,
Sadat

Comment: This error comes when sql server cannot identify the object you are referring. In this case issue is "[02Manual_DB].[dbo].[1558].[wallet]" you cannot you any table in the air. See answer from @samjudson. this should work

Answer (score 1):

You've specified the [1558] table name, without actually mentioning it in a `FROM` statement.

I think what you want is something like this:

```
UPDATE [02Manual_DB].[dbo].[manual DB]
SET [Box_MDB] = 'Box-1558'
FROM [02Manual_DB].[dbo].[manual DB] AS M
INNER JOIN [02Manual_DB].[dbo].[1558] AS W
ON W.[wallet] = M.[Wallet_MDB]
WHERE M.[Box_MDB] = 'Box-1158'
```

Obviously your SQL doesn't actually do anything, because it is updating the Box_MDB field to 'Box-1558' only where it already matches that value, but presumably your real code is doing something more useful...

Comment: You also need to remove the alias on the left hand side of the assignment in `SET` - the table to `UPDATE` has already been identified between the `UPDATE` and `SET` keywords.